# why is this if/else statement causing a div to not show up?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, image

I have an if/else statement that checks to see if an image displayed in the DOM was originally smaller than 600px wide, and if was, it resizes said image to a different width. However, sometimes the div class .tagmap does not appear. This happens only when the if/else statement is present. Any idea why as to why this is happening? I've generated [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuVaS/1/). The first image in step 2 and the image in step 4 are both supposed to have .tagmap appended

jQuery if/else statement

```
$('span.i_contact').each(function() {    
var imgWidth = $(this).data('img-width');    
if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600)*300);
    console.log(newWidth);   
    $(this).css({
        "width":newWidth
    });    
} 

else{    
    var pos_width = ($(this).data('pos-width')) / 2.025;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('pos-height')) / 2.025;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('pos-x')) / 2.025;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) / 2.025;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid orange",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });
}  
var n = $(this).data('index');
$('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode);

});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {    
var imgWidth = $(this).data('img-width');
if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600)*300);
    console.log(newWidth);   
    $(this).css({
        "width":newWidth
    });    
}    

else {
    var pos_width = ($(this).data('pos-width')) / 2.025;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('pos-height')) / 2.025;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('pos-x')) / 2.025;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) / 2.025;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid green",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
} 
var n = $(this).data('index');
$('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode);       
});
```

ERB (how the images are generated)

```
<div class="stepcontainer">
<div class="steptext">
    <%= step.instruction %>
</div>
<div class="modalbutton">
    <%= render(step.flags.new) %>   
</div>


<% if step.input_contact.present? %>
    <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-img-width="<%= step.i_connection.image.dimensions.first %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>   
    <div class="productimg">    
        <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">   
            <%= link_to image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium), class: "iconnection" ), "#{step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
            <div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <% if step.i_connection.cord? && !step.o_connection.dongle? %>
        <div class="cableimg">
            <%= image_tag(step.i_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "orange")  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>           
<% end %>   <!-- end of step.input_contact.present -->

<% if step.o_connection.cord? && !step.o_connection.dongle? %>
    <div class="cableimg">
        <%= image_tag(step.o_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "green") %>
    </div>      
<% end %>
<span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-img-width="<%= step.o_connection.image.dimensions.first %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
<div class="productimg">
    <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
        <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium), class: "oconnection"), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
        <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: different than this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/JuVaS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.data("img-width")` is wrong, it should be `.data("imgWidth")`

http://api.jquery.com/data

The same mistake is made several times throughout your code, such as `.data("pos-width")`

Comment: Thanks! Would I store the pos-width value into a variable and then call that variable in the data method?

Comment: I don't understand. you just need to change it to `.data("posWidth")` data attributes that are multiple words long, for example `data-foo-bar-abra-cadabra` are stored as `fooBarAbraCadabra`.